# docker-compose services not able to communicate with each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Below is my docker-compose.yml file having 3 services.

```
version: '3.0' 
services:   
   mongodb:
    build: ./mongodb
    image: mongo:1.0
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - appNetwork   

   node-service:
    build: ./node-service
    image: node-service-live:1.0
    container_name: node-service
    command: 
      sh -c "dockerize -wait tcp://mongodb:27017 -timeout 1m &&  npm start"
    expose:
      - "3031"
    ports:
      - "3031:3031"
    networks:
      - appNetwork   
   angular-app:
    build: ./angular-app
    image: angular-app-live:1.0
    container_name: angular-app
    command: ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201 --disable-host-check
    ports:
      - "4201:4201"
    networks:
      - appNetwork 

networks:   
   appNetwork:
     external: true
```

When I execute `docker-compose up`, `node-service` is able to connect to `mongodb` service using this link: `mongodb://mongodb:27017/DBName?authMechanism=DEFAULT`.

But `angular-app` service can't communicate with `node-service` despite being in same network. In `angular-app` I am using following link(`http://node-service:3031`) to connect to `node-service`.

What am I missing??

Comment: Is the Angular app running in a browser, outside of Docker space?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes angular app is running on browser at localhost:4201

Comment: The browser doesn't get to see the Docker-internal host names.  It needs an externally reachable address to the other service.  In a local-only development context `http://localhost:3031` might work, but this ultimately needs to be configurable at deployment time.

Comment: @DavidMaze http://localhost:3031 works perfectly but I have to deploy the app on server. And how mongodb's hostname gets resolved???

Comment: Say none of this was running in Docker; you were running three separate processes directly on the host, and you used something like Ansible to deploy them to your server.  How would you configure these URLs then?  From the point of view of the Angular app running in the browser it’s exactly the same.

Comment: @user9306205 The name `mongodb` could be solved as the communication between `mongodb` and `node-service` is internal of this compose project. But the javascript in `angular-app` would run out of this compose project(in browser), which meaning out of network named `appNetwork`. The embedded DNS for container name/service name would be valid just in the same network/or swarm cluster... BTW, it seems still okay if you deploy the app on server. `Localhost` is always valid with port mapping established(-ports: 3031:3031).